# Simulate enter key in text area for automation with javascript, no jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation

I'm building an automation tool and I'm trying to automate some comments.
The issue I'm facing is that I can't "submit" the comment.

I can get the comment/text in the textarea, I've tried doing .submit() but it just reloads the page, doesn't actually submit the comment. I think the actual submit is triggered by the enter keypress.

I attempted doing .focus() and then simulating the enter key but it didn't work.
Another issue might be that I'm running this code inside the browsers console, and i can't focus inside the textarea. I could be wrong though.

Also, the textarea doesn't have an ID, only a class. I'm trying to do this with pure JS, no jQuery.

```js
function enter1() {
    var commentEl = document.querySelector("._2hc0g");

   var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
   delete keyboardEvent.which;
   var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'initKeyboardEvent' : 'initKeyEvent';
   keyboardEvent[initMethod](
     'keydown', // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
     true, // bubbles
     true, // cancelable
     window, // viewArg: should be window
     false, // ctrlKeyArg
     false, // altKeyArg
     false, // shiftKeyArg
     false, // metaKeyArg
     13, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
     13 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
   );
   console.log("beefore querySelector");
   commentEl.focus();
   document.querySelector("._2hc0g").dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
   if(document.querySelector("._2hc0g").dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent)){
    console.log("key event worked");
   }
   console.log("after querySelector");
 }

function doComment() {
    var textAreaElement = $("textarea._2hc0g");
    var commentEl = document.querySelector("._2hc0g");

    
    textAreaElement.value = "Great photo here! I love it :)";
    commentEl.focus();
    enter1();
}
doComment();
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my apologies

Comment: No problem, I edited it for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you sir!

Comment: Probably the site uses it's own function to post the data to the backend instead of form submit.

Comment: @Danmoreng correct. Thats why I tried to focus and then simulate the enter key.

Comment: Just call that function from the console?

Comment: @Danmoreng I tried looking for the function but couldn't find what was being fired